# MailUp - Contract not signed, please login in console and accept terms of service

Tags: mailup

What are the steps that we do need to follow to resolve error-code 
`"Contract not signed, please login in console and accept terms of service."`

To Get the access token and the refresh token i am using following command

`curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD" /
        https://services.mailup.com/Authorization/OAuth/Token`

As mentioned in link:
http://help.mailup.com/display/mailupapi/Authenticating+with+OAuth+v2

Answer (score 0):

MailUp has a bug for which, after logging in, in the developer accounts, the popup for accepting the "terms of service" is not displayed. I contacted the support team and they should have solved the problem. This is the case at least for my account.

The command you have copy/pasted from documentation site do not work due to this bug.

So now you just have to log in to the control panel and accept the "terms of service", wait about an hour for their internal cache to be updated, and try to access the API again.